# Show next div's one at a time, using a single button - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Very new to jQuery, please bear with me. I've got a form with repeating fieldsets that i want show one at a time upon the user clicking a **single** button. Here's the basic layout:

```
<form>
   <fieldset>
       <input 1>
       <input 2>
       <div id="address-container">
           <fieldset> <!--  current address -->
               <input 3>
               <input 4>
           </fieldset>
           <div id ="previous-address-1" class="hidden">
           <fieldset>
               <input 5>
               <input 6>          
           </fieldset>
           </div>
           <div id ="previous-address-2" class="hidden">
           <fieldset>
               <input 5>
               <input 6>          
           </fieldset>
           </div>
           <div id ="previous-address-3" class="hidden">
           <fieldset>
               <input 5>
               <input 6>          
           </fieldset>
           </div>
       </div> <!--  close address-container -->
     <span class="button"><a href="#" id="show-hidden">Add a Previous Address</a></span>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

I can get all the .hidden-div's to show at once upon click, but i'm trying to accomplish showing them one at a time, with the user clicking again to add another nested form fieldset if needed. 
I realize that i could add more buttons and attach to each id and then hide them once they are clicked, but it seems like there should be a less verbose way using next() and/or eq().

Then again, maybe appending would be a better route??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: YOu need slider google it first

Comment: Definitely don't need a slider. I want the hidden items to stay visible in the DOM once shown. Thanks for the prompt reply though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) in your selector.

```
$('#show-hidden').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#address-container .hidden:eq(0)').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/aMuHAhe/1/edit

**Update: Hide link after all are shown**

```
$('#show-hidden').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#address-container .hidden:eq(0)').removeClass('hidden');

    if($('#address-container .hidden').length == 0){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

This checks to see if there are any elements inside #address-container that have the hidden class. If nothing is found, .length will be 0. $(this) is the #show-hidden link.

Comment: This fiddle is showing exactly what i'm trying to do, but i'm having trouble implementing it in to my form. Would having other divs surrounding the entire form cause an issue with the selector as you have shown it?

Comment: No, they shouldn't, as long as you don't have anything else using the same ID. The selector is finding the element with id="address-container", then inside that it finds all the elements with class="hidden", but only selects the first one. If you want to show more code or a link, maybe I'll see something else.

Comment: I didn't notice it right away, but the code you put in place in your jsbin has a typo. You should be using `.removeClass('hidden')`. You have a period ('.hidden').

Comment: AHHHAAA!!! Thank you so much for the code and for spotting the erroneous period. You just made my day :) Any chance you could add to that how you might hide the button once the last div is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
   var elem= $('.hidden:first');
   if($('.show').length)
   {
      elem=$('.show').next('div.hidden');
      $('.show').removeClass('show');
   }
   elem.addClass('show');
   return false;// to prevent for submit
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/eCUSAze/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Where do i need to insert the .show class in my example to make this work?

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I went with AndrewR's slightly more elegant fix. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
var i = 0;
$("#show-hidden").click(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();

var j = (i%3)+ 1;


$("#previous-address-"+j).removeClass('hidden');

$("#address-container").find("div").not(document.getElementById("previous-address-"+j)).addClass('hidden');

i++;
});


});
```

Here I declared a global variable `i=0` . Everytime the link is clicked the value of `j` cycles among 1 2 and 3 like 1,2,3,1,2,3..... And contents of div with the id calculated from j is shown while others are hidden.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ubEsEru/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I ended up going with AndrewR's as it was more concise.